# Car takes several cranks to start, but once started it drives fine | Good Battery & Good Starter

Tags: starting, mini-cooper

So its 2010 R56 model. The battery, starter is good and tested well. However, it takes several crank cycles for it to start. Initially i used to do 7 or 8 short cranks (4 seconds) each for it to start.

Today I noticed that if I continue the first crank for say 9 - 10 seconds, it will start on the second crank.

I read through mini forums and they mention that it could be HPFP issue, but why would the car start in second crank when it fails to start on the long first crank duration?

So even if I continue the first crank duration for say 15 seconds it wont start! This doesnt sound like HPFP issue, right?

---

After further research online it does look like HPFP issue more specifically: [source](https://www.northamericanmotoring.com/forums/stock-problems-issues/298688-what-fails-inside-the-hpfp.html)

> The problem with the Mini Cooper S High Pressure fuel pump failing is
> an internal non return valve which fails and allows pressurized fuel
> to leak back into the fuel tank and as a result upon start-up has a
> lack of sufficient fuel to the injectors causing misfiring until the
> pump has built up sufficient pressure.

This looks like to symptoms I am facing, once the car starts after several attempts or cranking, the HPFP must have built enough fuel pressure to cause ignition and once the car starts the RPM continually supplies the fuel faster to HPFP

---

Upon diagnostics the following fault codes were given off:

P1105: (ECM) has detected a fault or malfunction with the Manifold Absolute Pressure (MAP)/Barometric (BARO) pressure switch solenoid valve.

P111A: [not sure what this is exactly](http://p111a.enginetroublecode.com/)

P0420:

Comment: If you don't think it's battery or fuel, check for spark?

Comment: Does it make any difference if you leave the ignition on for 10 seconds before starting to crank?

Comment: @findwindow - I'd bet if the car is ultimately starting, it's not the ignition which is at fault. I'd highly suggest this is a fueling issue, but the OP would need to test the fuel pressure.

Comment: @findwindow I added new iridium spark plugs as well as tested coils. They are fine. I doubt that spark is an issue

Comment: @HandyHowie let me try that and update

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 but if its fueling issue then why the car wont start in the first 15 seconds of cranking? It rather works if I crank for the first time 9 seconds and then the second for 3 seconds totalling 12 seconds. I believe the total cranking time for both the scenerios should sufficiently provide the fuel. My confusion for diagnosis is coming from the need for second crank.

Comment: You can always test this theory by spraying flammable liquid (starting fluid) down the intake during first startup. If it fires right away, it's a fueling issue.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, thats a very helpful tip. Shall try it.

Comment: Is this starting behavior consistent, or does it vary if the engine is hot or cold?

Comment: @GdD it does vary if the engine is hot or cold. The starting behavior is inconsistent. If I had driven it for a while then it takes few cranks to start again. However next morning (cold engine) it would take more cranks. Does it indicate something?

Comment: @GdD Is your diagnosis might be about HPFP .. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a check valve (aka non-return valve) causing your problems,
the challenge is that yours is built into the high pressure fuel pump. The HPFP is an expensive part, you would want to exhaust other options before you spend on it, and do more diagnostic work.

You may be able to get fuel pressure readings using an OBD reader, I would start there and see what readings you get before and after starting when hot and cold. If the fuel pressure is very low before starting then it's very possibly the check valve. Your options would be to get the pump repaired (not sure if that's possible or economical), replace the pump, or you may be able to add a non-return valve in-line. It could also be that your low pressure or high pressure pump is starting to fail and don't operate well until they run for a bit.

Comment: Ok, So I was unable to confirm the fuel pressure using OBD because it wasnt supported in my device. The fault codes I got were P1105, P111A and P0420. So it could be MAF, HPFP or something I yet have to figure out

Comment: They could be old codes, did you clear them? If you clear them and they don't come back they aren't a concern. P111A is an injector circuit failure code, but it can trip because of low fuel pressure. P0420 is an emissions code and is almost certainly unrelated.

Comment: yes, I did clear them and got P1105 & P111A as "pending fault codes". The ECU would confirm it after successive runs i guess.

Comment: If you had a problem with an injector or the maf you'd be having rough running or other issues after start. P1105 could be a pressure differential sensor, not a MAF, or you could have a leak in the intake system, a common fault is a cracked breather tube. It's probably a problem of some kind but I'm not convinced it's the source of your starting problems.

Comment: this makes so much sense! I am gonna get better OBD to get additional readings on sensors.