# Mini Cooper R56 Trouble Starting with (P1105, P111A) codes

Tags: starting, obd-ii, mini-cooper

My R56 Mini had trouble starting (5-7) cranks to start it and lots of misfires, bad idling etc. I originally posted the problem [here](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/89086/car-takes-several-cranks-to-start-but-once-started-it-drives-fine-good-batter) and tested for fuel pressure, it is nominal thought.

After replacing ignition coils, misfires are gone and the car runs smooth once started! Hurray! But the starting problem still persists! Could it be due to bad [VANOS solenoid](https://www.northamericanmotoring.com/forums/r56-hatch-talk-2007/283818-rough-idle-after-warmup-but-runs-ok-cleaning-vanos-solenoids.html) eventhough I dont have rough idling its really smooth idling after the replacement of ignition coils.

These are the new [fault codes](https://www.minimania.com/Mini_Cooper_Gen_II_OBDII_Powertrain_Codes) I am getting:

P1105 - Differential Pressure Sensor Intake Manifold Pressure Too High (Bank 1)

P111A - Mass or Volume Air Flow va O2 Sensor Too High (Bank 1)

Does this combination of code hint towards something?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add a comment but I need 50 points to do that.

Try cleaning the breather pipe and the sensors, I used brake cleaners in the past. It looks like the values of your sensors are high regardless, this could also be due to open circuit so check that as well.